# XLookupString does not detect 2 byte char language

Tags: c++, linux, x11, xlib

I am using X11 library ,when I change keyboard language (for example Russian) I can't detect 2 bytes char like this : "ф" 
how should i change this part of code :

```
XEvent  ev;
if(ev.type==EVENT_KEY_RELEASE  || ev.type==EVENT_KEY_PRESS){
    XLookupString(KeyEvent,&cChar,1,&keysym,NULL);
}
```

this part working correctly for English language but for Russian cChar is empty, should I use other function instead of XLookupString?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For non-latin characters you should be using one of `XmbLookupString`, `XwcLookupString` or `Xutf8LookupString` see the [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/xmblookupstring) for details.